# AWS Capped IOPS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, provisioned-iops

I am facing an issue using AWS.

Firstly I have set up a Free Tier db.t2.micro with just 20GB storage.

I then created an elastic beanstalk EC2 instance and deployed a simple php script which inserts 1000 records into the database described above. It took around 10 seconds for this to complete.

I then wanted to look at reducing the amount of time it takes to complete this process. I increased the capacity of the RDS instance to a dbt2.medium and allocated 300GB SSD storage in order to increase the max iops.

Looking at the metrics when I run the script again I am still only getting a maximum of 100 iops. Its almost like something is throttling it and the time taken to complete the script is about the same.

Both the instances are in the same VPC. What would be causing this? and how would I go about trying to complete this in say 1 second?

[image]

Comment: Didnt I answer this for you yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500763/mysql-rds-instance-performance-on-amazon-webservice/43501573#43501573

Comment: Hi Harry, I have increased the iops by adding 300gb ssd storage however the metrics show that it never exceeds 100 per second. I'm not sure why this is happening

Comment: Probably because of the overhead. I dont think your EC2 instance is the bottleneck, you should batch up your inserts into 100 at a time and you'll get very high throughput.